# Android widget, distinguish if onUpdate triggered by periodical or click update?

Tags: android, android-widget

I'm implementing a simple widget that updates periodically and by clicking it, no problem so far.

I would however like the widget to behave slightly different if updated by the periodic timer or by clicking it.

But I cant figure out how to distinguish if

```
onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds)
```

gets triggered by periodic timer set by `updatePeriodMillis` or by the click `PendingIntent`.

Is this possible or does my question not make any sense?

Thanks!

Comment: How about passing another parameter to that function?